# why ping results changes

Tags: operating-system, ping, ubuntu-14.04

I have been experiencing this and found no one else who had this happening.

[picture will be included here when I get the needed reputation to post it]

I took this picture as an example (so, yes, I know package 2106 has been received and its displayed. Its just to illustrate.) but it has happened that 100+ lost packages got counted back after a while(for example, I have 200/100 right now and some time later I have 2070/2040) but that doesn't happens always. That means my results are inconclusive and unpredictable which means I cannot use it. I need to find out why the ping is not working properly. I have not edited any network file and this is a ubuntu 14.04 64bits. Does anyone have any hint as what is happening here?

Comment: you can upload the picture in picasa and put the link in comment

Comment: Lol Ganesh likes me :D thanks.
[picture](http://s2.postimg.org/mf9d1xq7t/pingweird.jpg)
As I stated its just to illustrate. On this occasion the ping was sent and I asked for results before it could come back, so, ok,  for a difference of 2 lost packages going to 1 lost package its just because that package was not received back YET. But for 30+ packages being recounted minutes after they were sent its a very strange situation taking into account that default ping should count 2 seconds delays as lost packages. Also, the packages that changed to counted didn't got show as received by console.

Comment: (And Yes, I need to capture the packages to provide further information but I didn't had the time to do that yet. And its not always that this behavior happens which makes hard to reproduce.)